# Replace strings between pair of characters

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, cut

There's a file named `sites.txt` and it contains dynamic sites with long URLs like this:

```
http://onesite.com/a.php?one=1&two=2&three=3
http://anothersite.com/b.php?one=1&two=2    
http://aaaandanothersite.com/a.php?one=1&two=2&three=3&four=4
```

And I have to remove all of parameter values, having output like this:

```
http://onesite.com/a.php?one=&two=&three=    
http://anothersite.com/b.php?one=&two=    
http://aaaandanothersite.com/a.php?one=&two=&three=&four=
```

If there's a regex or something shortcut, I like to hear it.
But if there's no way doing this in this one-line way, sites already in a for function, so also can be handled line-by-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/=[^&]*(&|$)/=\1/g' sites.txt
```

replace `=` followed by any character (except `\n`ewline) but not a `&` character (zero-or-mote times) `[^&]*` that ends with `&` or `|` end of line `$` (`(&|$)`), ***with*** just `=` and return back captured group `(&|$)` with its `\1` as back-reference which is `&` character or nothing where it indicates that was the last parameter.

Answer (score 2):

With Perl you could run something along the lines of

```
perl -ple 's/=[^&=]*/=/g' sites.txt
```

where:

- `perl -ple exp` is equivalent to *for each line without the termination, print(exp(line))*